# how to install botdispatch with npm in cloud cli?

Tags: azure, npm, botframework

I wanted to make a chatbot with(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=python)

The tutorial asks me to install botdispatch with npm. So I use "npm i -g npm" in cloud cli,but I can't do that due to permission denied.

Is there some way I can solve this in cloud cli?
Or I need to install cli locally?

Comment: Are you trying to create and develop a bot entirely in the cloud? are you not using a development environment and then pushing to the cloud? Typically you either create your bot on a dev environment, or create the bot in the cloud, then download to modify it in a dev environment. dispatch is typically run on that dev environment to configure what is needed.